# How do I properly execute SQL queries with optional parameters in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have an application where users are allowed to set filters on a set of data.  For instance:

```
cursor.execute("select * from products where price <= %s", (price))
```

But I would like to have the possibility of optional filter elements.  For instance:

```
cursor.execute("select * from products where price <= %s and size >= %s and weight <= %s", (price,size,weight))
```

What is the proper way of constructing this query?  It is possible to use the % wildcard as a value, but this seems very hacky.  Users may specify one, several, or none of the filters.

Comment: Have you considered using a ORM?

Comment: You might consider using SQLAlchemy, either for its ORM, or for its "SQL Expression Language," which makes building queries programmatically quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, using an ORM such as SQLAlchemy would be able to solve your problem in a generic sense. However if you didn't want to use an ORM for some reason and wanted to build this you could use dynamic SQL. This is where you manually build the sql for each request. It is often considered a poor practice and can lead to lots of security vulnerabilities, especially injections, if not done carefully. Now if you didn't have to worry about any columns being NULL then you could set default values for example:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE price < %s AND weight > %s
```

And your params could be (assuming no filters)

```
(9999999999999999,-1)
```

However with filters price > 500

```
(500, -1)
```

And so on. The other way would be more dynamic.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM products"
filters = None
if price:
   filters = filters + " price > %s"
if filters:
   sql = "{0} WHERE {1}".format(sql, filters)
```